# HTML5 Promise : does resolve call end promise

Tags: javascript, html, promise, ecmascript-6

for example we have a promise like `var prom = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){...})`

and in that , when some condition is satisfied, we call resolve, would that end the promise call, or must we explicitly call `return` after calling `resolve(params)`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "end the promise call"? The call to the `resolver` function that you pass to the `Promise` constructor?

Comment: By end, i mean none of the statements after resolve should execute

Comment: No, `resolve` is "just a function". Calling it does not have any special `return` or `throw` semantics.

Comment: Adding to what Bergi wrote - the point of explicit construction is often to interoperable with callback APIs, so requiring a `return` wouldn't have made sense. On the other hand - throwing will reject to preserve throw safety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the code following `resolve` statement will be still executed. That's why this is your responsibility to design your logic so that there are no unexpected operations. You can return or you can use `if-else` blocks.

It's easy to see:

```
var prom = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    resolve(123);
    console.log('still working')
});
prom.then(function(data) { console.log(data) });
```

The result will be

```
still working
123
```

Note however that `still working` comes *before* resolution callback even thought it's been resolved after one.